# Which UI designer to use with GtkSharp: Glade, GtkBuilder or Stetic?

Tags: interface-builder, gtk#, glade, gtkbuilder

Which interface tool would you recommend I use for creating user interfaces for GtkSharp applications?

I started with Glade, because it has wrappers in GtkSharp and allows for loading widgets from resource files. But then I found advise to use GtkBuilder instead of Glade, because Glade will be replaced by GtkBuilder in future releases of Gtk. Is it true? Furthermore, it seems for UI generation MonoDevelop uses Stetic which extends Glade. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Glade (the application) and libglade (the library). Libglade is a library that has been replaced by GtkBuilder and so you should not use it. Glade the application is the UI designer, which can save GtkBuilder files, or libglade files for compatibility.

Stetic ties in with Mono and MonoDevelop a bit more, and so if you use MonoDevelop then you should probably use Stetic.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. I am going to use Visual Studio for backend code, Glade (the application) for design UI, and GtkBuilder as format of stored UI. And Gtk# Beans as .Net library for using GtkBuilder format.